# An error when I run the following code in data science with python in coursera

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have an error when I run the following codes for the question.
Question:
Let's explore the relationship between being fed breastmilk as a child and getting a seasonal influenza vaccine from a healthcare provider. Return a tuple of the average number of influenza vaccines for those children we know received breastmilk as a child and those who know did not.

This function should return a tuple in the form (use the correct numbers):

(2.5, 0.1)

codes:

```
def average_influenza_doses():
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    # raise NotImplementedError()
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.read_csv("assests/NISPUF17.csv", index_col=0)
   
    cbf_flu=df.loc[:,['CBF_01','P_NUMFLU']]
   
   
    cbf_flu1=cbf_flu[cbf_flu['CBF_01'] ==1].dropna()
    cbf_flu2=cbf_flu[cbf_flu['CBF_01'] ==2].dropna()
   
    flu1=cbf_flu1['P_NUMFLU'].values.copy()
    flu1[np.isnan(flu1)] = 0
    f1=np.sum(flu1)/len(flu1)
   
    flu2=cbf_flu2['P_NUMFLU'].values.copy()
    flu2[np.isnan(flu2)] = 0
    f2=np.sum(flu2)/len(flu2)
   
    aid =(f1,f2)
    return aid
```

assert `len(average_influenza_doses())==2`, "Return two values in a tuple, the first for yes and the second for no."

Comment: Hi, welcome to the StackOverflow community. Please read this helpful post to ask better questions. Please share the errors you get. Providing the input you have and the output you want will help to answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

You mispelled the directory

**WRONG**

```
df = pd.read_csv("assests/NISPUF17.csv", index_col=0)
```

**RIGHT**

```
df = pd.read_csv("**assets**/NISPUF17.csv", index_col=0)
```

I only found this mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this. Instead of using `.values`, just get the Pandas Series and apply the aggregate function `.sum()` to it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def average_influenza_doses():

    df = pd.read_csv("assets/NISPUF17.csv", index_col=0)

    cbf_flu = df[['CBF_01','P_NUMFLU']]


    cbf_flu1 = cbf_flu[cbf_flu['CBF_01'] == 1].dropna()
    cbf_flu2 = cbf_flu[cbf_flu['CBF_01'] == 2].dropna()

    flu1 = cbf_flu1['P_NUMFLU']
    f1 = flu1.sum() / flu1.size

    flu2 = cbf_flu2['P_NUMFLU']
    f2 = flu2.sum() / flu2.size

    print(f1, f2)
    return (f1,f2)
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to fix your file source where you're reading the csv from.

Answer (score 0):

### One of the ways to answer this question:

Type the following code to read the given dataset

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv',index_col=0)
df
```

Main code

```
def average_influenza_doses():
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    BF_Flu=df[df['CBF_01']==1]
    avg_BF=BF_Flu['P_NUMFLU'].mean()
    NBF_Flu=df[df['CBF_01']==2]
    avg_NBF=NBF_Flu['P_NUMFLU'].mean()
    tup=(avg_BF,avg_NBF)
    return tup
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Execute using the following code

```
average_influenza_doses()
```

Check using the following code as already given

```
assert len(average_influenza_doses())==2, "Return two values in a tuple, the first for yes and the second for no."
```

[CBF_01]=1 - Received breast milk

[CBF_01]=1 - Not received breast milk

[P_NUMFLU] - No. of children affected by flu

Answer (score 0):

```
    def average_influenza_doses():
    # YOUR CODE HERE
        df=pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv',index_col=0)
        bf = df[df['CBF_01']==1]
        nbf = df[df['CBF_01']!=1]
        mean_bf = bf['P_NUMFLU'].mean()
        mean_nbf = nbf['P_NUMFLU'].mean()
        return ((mean_bf,mean_nbf))
```

Answer (score 0):

def average_influenza_doses():

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("assets/NISPUF17.csv", index_col=0)
new_df = df[(df["CBF_01"]==1).dropna() | (df["CBF_01"]==2).dropna()]
a,b=new_df.groupby(["CBF_01"]).P_NUMFLU.mean()
tup = (a,b)
return tup
raise NotImplementedError()
```

Comment: Would you double-check your comment and fix formatting?
Don't know what you meant here, but pretty sure that it's not in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
def average_influenza_doses():
    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv')
    df_milk=df[df['CBF_01']==1]
    df_nomilk=df[df['CBF_01']==2]
    a=df_milk['P_NUMFLU'].mean()
    b=df_nomilk['P_NUMFLU'].mean()
    return (a,b)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).